# Class object is null within a util class always which is causing NPE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Getting null pointer exception in DAProvider class as the TrialHolder object is always null. When I wired the TrialHolder directly to another class it works , but when I use it via DAProvider , it is null

Any help is much appreciated...

Below are the relevant classes and configurations I have made :

This where the interceptor is added

```
import com.role.server.grpc.TrialInterceptorInterceptor;
import com.servicelibs.grpc.Grpc;
import io.grpc.Server;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class GrpcConfig {
  @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public Server grpcServer(
      Grpc grpc,
          TrialInterceptorInterceptor trialInterceptor)
      throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Server server =
        grpc.newServerBuilder()
            .addService(testConfigServiceGrpc)
            .withInterceptors(
                trialInterceptor)
            .build();

    //other logic in place 

    return server;
  }
}
```

Below is where the interceptor is defined

```
package com.role.server.grpc;

import com.role.server.grpc.ms.grpc.TrialHolder;
import com.spiffe.sc;
import com.spiffe.sp;
import com.libs.oc.xfcc.XForwardedClientCert;
import com.libs.oc.xfcc.XForwardedClientCertList;
import io.grpc.*;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TrialInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  @Autowired TrialHolder TrialHolder;
  private static final Metadata.Key<String> HK =
      Metadata.Key.of("x-forwarded-client-cert", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

  /**
   * Intercept a gRPC call and inject context.
   */
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
      Metadata metadata,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {

    Optional<sci> sci = getContextInfoFromClientCert(metadata);
    if (!sci.isEmpty()) {
      TrialHolder.setsu(sci.get().getsu());
      TrialHolder.setsn(sci.get().getsn());
    } else {
      log.warn("sc is empty");
    }

    return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(
        serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata)) {

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
        super.onComplete();
      }
    };
  }


  private Optional<sci> getContextInfoFromClientCert(Metadata metadata) {
    String xH = metadata.get(HK);
    XForwardedClientCertList clientCerts = XForwardedClientCertList.fromString(xH);
   if (clientCerts.size() > 1) {
      return clientCerts.stream()
          .map(this::buildsci)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .findFirst();
    } else {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }

  private sci buildsci(
      XForwardedClientCert xforwardedClientCert) {
   //logic to handle and return 
    return new sci(
        sc.get().getService().get(), xforwardedClientCert.getSanUri());
  }
}
```

Below is the object which I want to pass around

```
package com.role.server.grpc.service.grpc;

import com.libs.opencontext.api.Key;
import com.libs.opencontext.impl.ocProvider;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class TrialHolder {

  private final ocProvider socProvider;

  @Autowired
  public TrialHolder(ocProvider socProvider) {
    this.socProvider = socProvider;
  }

  private void addToContext(Key<String> key, String value) {
    if (socProvider.isPresent() && !StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
      socProvider.currentContext().put(key, value);
    } 
  }

  <T> Optional<T> getFromContext(Key<T> key) {
    if (socProvider.isPresent()) {
      return Optional.ofNullable(socProvider.currentContext().get(key));
    } else {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }

//logic defined for below 
  public Optional<String> getsu() {
    return getFromContext("su");
  }

  public void setsu(String su) {
    addToContext("su", su);
  }

  public void setsn(String falconTeam) {
    addToContext("sn", falconTeam);
  }

  public Optional<String> getsn() {
    return getFromContext("sn");
  }

  public boolean isPresent() {
    return socProvider.isPresent();
  }
}
```

The below class is where trialHolder is coming in as null

```
package com.metadata.da.utils;
import com.role.server.grpc.md.grpc.trialHolder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DAProvider {
  private final TrialHolder trialHolder;

  public boolean checkHolder() {
    return  trialHolder.getsn().isPresent()
  }
}
```

Usage of DAprovider

```
package com.md.dataaccess;


import com.md.da.utils.DAProvider;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConfigProvider {
  private final DAProvider daProvider;

  @Override
  public Config createConfig() {
     return daProvider.checkHolder()
  }
  }
```

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dACController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ConfigProvider' defined in file ----: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessConfigV1Provider' defined in file -----: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 8; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daProvider' defined in file ---: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.role.server.grpc.service.grpc.TrialHolder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:`

Comment: Is the bean `TrialHolder` discovered? I.e. what is (are) the root package(s) for bean discovery?

Comment: Please post the full text of the exception and stack trace. @Turing85 as `DAProvider` is using constructor injection, won't the spring context fail to start if there's no `TrialHolder`?

Comment: And please show the bean that `DAProvider` is used in.

Comment: @tgdavies hmm... true...

Comment: the @ComponentScan("com.role") happens at this package level

Comment: `DAProvider` is in `com.metadata`.

Comment: Please also show the class where `DAProvider` is injected and `checkHolder` is called.

Comment: updated the usage of DAProvider, once I made private final TrialHolder trialHolder
I am getting the following error 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ConfigProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daProvider';

Comment: So perhaps because `com.metadata` is not being scanned.

Comment: added the trace

Comment: Or rather because `com.role`isn't being scanned.

Comment: I tried creating the DAProvider in the same package as the ConfigProvider but it dint help